# Use scrapy to get list of urls, and then sent request only not in the given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape a website once a day, but only new content. So far I've set a Rule that already scraped urls would not be scraped, but what I want is to mark those urls as arleady scraped. In other words, I do not want to sent a request, but to put that url in list variable.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='next-page-block no-print']/a"), follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='list-item']/a", deny=alreadyScraped), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
)
```

can I check if url is in the list, if not then sent a request, if it is - put in a list variable.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='next-page-block no-print']/a"), follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='list-item']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='checkIfScraped')

def checkIfScraped(self, request):
    #code here
```

**EDIT:**

```
def checkIfScraped(self, request):
    if request.url in self.alreadyScraped:
        #put url in a list
    else:
        return request
```

I'm able to collect those urls, but is it possible to output them in the same output as parse_item?

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    yield {
        'url': response.request.url,
        'new': 1
    }
```

if url goes to that already scraped list, I need to yield {..., 'new': 0}

Comment: if request.url in self.alreadyScraped - yield {..., 'new': 0} else - scrape with new:1, right?

Comment: I recommend that you switch to a regular `Spider` instead of a `CrawlSpider`, they are more flexible.